# Require socket.io-client from installed socket.io package

Tags: node.js, socket.io, client, npm

According to the [socket.io-client readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client/) there's a way to access this module from an installed socket.io package. Something similar is stated on [the site](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#). However the only way I've managed to 'require' socket.io-client is by using the arguably hacky:

```
require('socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client')
```

What's the quote-unquote correct way of requiring this package?

Background info: I have a nodejs module that's running a socket.io server (hence I have socket.io installed), but I'd also like to run a client so that i can connect to some other server. The normal way of doing this would be to just npm install socket.io-client and then require that package. But since socket.io-client is a dependency of socket.io, i'd like to access it through this other package.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a new answer now that I understand you want to do initiate socket.io connections from your node server.

On [this page](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/) in the socket.io doc, it shows that you can do this:

```
var ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
```

to get access to the client-side socket.io functionality from your server.  I have not tried it myself.

There's also a piece of server-side client code example here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client.

Node.JS (server-side usage)
Add socket.io-client to your package.json and then:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect', function(){});
socket.on('event', function(data){});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question wasn't too clear. What I mean is that from the SAME nodejs script i'd like to have both a server and client running. The server does its own stuff, the client does its own stuff. I wanted to know how i can 'require' socket.io-client, when all i have installed in my npm package is socket.io. (socket.io-client is a dependency of socket.io, so it should somehow be nicely accessible.)
e: thanks for this response though, at least I know what the documentation was referring to now. :)

Comment: @jarekwg - I've redone my answer now that I understand you want to initiate socket.io connections from your nodejs server.  It looks like you can do that via the `socket.io-client` module.

Comment: require('socket.io-client') complains that the module isn't found, whereas including it in the package.json works, but results in duplication of the client module.

Comment: @jarekwg - I think you have to get that socket.io-client module.